# Proof of a trigonometric inequality with a parameter

Tags: inequality

Let
$$
f_p(x)=\left(-p^3-3 p^2-3 p-1\right) \sin
   \left(x-\frac{3 x}{p}\right)+\left(3 p^3+3
   p^2-15 p-23\right) \sin
   \left(x-\frac{x}{p}\right)+\left(-3 p^3+3
   p^2+15 p-23\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{p}+x\right)+\left(p^3-3 p^2+3
   p-1\right) \sin \left(\frac{3 x}{p}+x\right).
$$
I want to show
$$
f_p(x)>0,\; x\in(0,\pi/2)
$$
for any integer $p\ge2$. This trigonometric inequality has been verified by Mathematica using the Plot commend. However, I cannot give a rigorous proof of it.
For $p=7$, it is verified here.
[Proof of a trigonometric inequality in $(0,\pi/2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175443/proof-a-trigonometric-inequality-in-0-pi-2/2175521#2175443)
I can also verify $p=2,3,4,5,6$. However, I can not prove for general $p$. Any suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: How about computing the derivative, finding the minimum, and showing it's positive even at the minimum?

Comment: Alternatively, could try showing it by induction.

Comment: Another direction: if $g(p,x) = \left(-p^3-3 p^2-3 p-1\right) \sin \left(x-\frac{3 x}{p}\right)$ then you are adding $g(p,x) + g(-p,x)$ (and similarly for the other two terms). Not sure if that helps.

Comment: By plotting in Mathematica, it's shown $f_p(x)$ is monotonically increasing in $x\ge0$ for fixed $p$.

Comment: You can't prove things by plotting graphs; you can merely convince yourself of the truth of the theorem

Comment: I can see that the first and last terms are $-(1+p)^3\sin\left(x-\frac{3x}{p}\right)$ and $-(1-p)^3\sin\left(x+\frac{3x}{p}\right)$.  Is there a similar structure for the other two terms?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I thought the same but no nice expression is found for the other two terms (tried them in wolramalpha), that is, $3p^3+3p^2-15p-23$ does not have three "nice" zeroes (even worse, it only has one real one)

Comment: Unfortunately, $(-3 p^3+3p^2+15 p-23)$ and $(3 p^3+3p^2-15 p-23)$ cannot be factored.

Comment: Perhaps proof by induction is a good idea, but it seems complicated.

Comment: @LCH Yes I can confirm that after some rough workings, a proof by induction will be a few pages long

Comment: For small values of $x$, by Taylor, $$f_p(x)=\left(\frac{56}{15 p^4}-\frac{16}{3 p^2}+\frac{8}{5}\right) x^5+O\left(x^7\right)$$

Comment: Can you confirm that in the second **and** in the third term it is $-23$, and not $-23$ and $+23$ ?

Comment: yes, I confirm again they are -23 and -23.