# Proof of a trigonometric inequality involving $\sin x$ with a parameter

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let
$$
g_p(x)=\left(-2 p^4+12 p^2-26\right) \sin
   (x)+\left(p^4-6 p^2-8 p-3\right) \sin
   \left(x-\frac{2 x}{p}\right)+\left(p^4-6 p^2+8
   p-3\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 x}{p}+x\right).
$$
I want to show
$$
g_p(x)<0,\; x\in(0,\pi/2)
$$
for any $p\ge2$ (Note that $p$ may not be an integer). This trigonometric inequality has been verified by Mathematica using the Plot commend for a couple values of p. However, I cannot give a rigorous proof of it. Any suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Is this related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175862/proof-of-a-trigonometric-inequality-with-a-parameter?

Comment: Yes, on differentiating $f_p(x)$ in the link above, we are led to the equivalent inequality $g_p(x)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true for large p
because everything cancels out
except 32 sin(x).

You might try using
$\sin(a\pm b)
=\sin a \cos b \pm \cos a \sin b
$ and see what the
coefficients of
sin x and cos x 
are.

Comment: Using the sum formula, I obtain $g_p(x)=-2 p^4 \sin (x) \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)-2
   p^4 \sin (x)+2 p^4 \sin (x) \cos
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+12 p^2 \sin (x)
   \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+12 p^2 \sin
   (x)-12 p^2 \sin (x) \cos
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+6 \sin (x) \sin
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)-6 \sin (x) \cos
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+32 p \cos (x) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{p}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)-26 \sin (x)$

Comment: Now the problem is how to deal with $sin (x/p)$ and $cos (x/p)$. Note that $p$ may not be an integer.

Comment: Or $g_p(x)=\left(-2 p^4+12 p^2+6\right) \sin (x) \sin
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+\left(-2 p^4+12
   p^2-26\right) \sin (x)+\left(2 p^4-12
   p^2-6\right) \sin (x) \cos
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+32 p \cos (x) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{p}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)$

Comment: I also found $g_p(x)=\left(-4 p^4+24 p^2+12\right) \sin (x) \sin
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)+32 p \cos (x) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{p}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)-32 \sin (x)$.